# Is there a way to listen for a specific preference change (outside a PreferenceActivity)

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preference

Wondering what the suggested way to 'listen' for a specific preference change outside of a PreferenceActivity.  I have a PreferenceActivity that deals with all my sharedpreferences, but I also have a MapActivity that deals with map stuff.  How do I detect changes in a particular preference in the MapActivity, i.e. lets say a MapType preference.

Options I know about.

1. Implement OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener on my MapActivity.  I could set up the MapActivity as a listener and check if the preference that comes in is one I care about.  Problem with this is that I will get called for all preference changes not just the MapType preference that I care about.
2. In the onResume method in my MapActivity  check the preference I care about to see if it changed (since changes in settings right now mean I go to a new activity and then back to the map activity when done).  I don't like this because if I change the way I set the MapType (ie if it does not require a new activity) I would not hit onResume.
3. ???  Not sure if this is possible, but in the MapActivity (like onCreate) I get a hold of the MapType Preference class (don't think this is possible).  But if I could get a hold of that preferences actualy Preference class I could use the Preference. OnPreferenceChangeListener() and I would be listening for only that preference to be changed.

Comment: I get the shared preference as I need it, rather than storing a static snapshot of it. So if its ever changed, from any location, it will be picked up instantly

Comment: Sure but in the case of a MapType change I might need to know about it right when it changed.  I.E. if the map is showing when the preference changes I need the map to change.  I can't just loop forever checking if ti changed and do something.  I can listen, but point being it seems I have to listen for everything not just the one thing I want to listen to .